# Linar regression on pandas gives null as regression score

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

my_y = np.array([2, 5, 6, 10]).reshape(1, -1)
my_x = np.array([19, 23, 22, 30]).reshape(1,-1)

lm = LinearRegression()
lm = lm.fit(my_x, my_y)
result = lm.score(my_x, my_y)   
print(result)

Why does  this  give Nan as output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `reshape(-1, 1)` for arrays

```
my_y = np.array([2,5,6,10]).reshape(-1, 1)
my_x = np.array([19,23,22,30]).reshape(-1, 1)

lm = sk.LinearRegression()
lm = lm.fit(my_x, my_y)
result = lm.score(my_x, my_y)
print(result)

0.9302407516147975
```

Comment: Thanks , works fine now , so the array has to be long not wide ?